# Parts identification (some may not be Lego) bugle, cart, vehicle front, broken-glass texture

Tags: part-identification

Some more odd parts from the large bag of unsorted Lego I recently acquired.
Hope that someone can identify them.

The 2 pieces on the right are probably NOT Lego. No logos on there.
The colors are exact Lego shades though and the push-bar on the shopping cart piece fits a Lego Friends mini-fig hand.

The trans-clear orange canopy has a "broken-glass" texture cast in the plastic (it is not a visual only). Bottom side is normal.

The stickers on the 1x4 slope are a mess. There are 3 stickers on it side-by side, with an extra Shell logo sticker on top of the Ferrari sticker in the center.
(The nose-cone/front-wing piece is probably from the same Ferrari themed set.)

I would have though the canopy piece and the race-car nose would be easy to find on BrickLink but I can't find them.

[image: bugle, cart, vehicle front, broken-glass texture]

Comment: The bugle looks like a [Playmobil one](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/CzYAAOSwv~laujM5/s-l400.jpg) to me

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid Was my first guess as well but mine is slightly larger and differently shaped.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid and Playmobil of course is just enough thicker that it can break Lego clips/hands.  Keep well away

Comment: That shopping cart looks like it'd be rather small in scale for a minifig.  And it's definitely too small for Playmobil, which are a bit larger than LEGO.  (Unfortunately, it's nearly impossible to search for "shopping cart" as every website that sells toys or anything else has a virtual "shopping cart" for checkout, so you get too many false positives.)

Comment: [Playmobil Bugle Horn Musical Instrument](https://www.ebay.com/itm/284560951506) on EBay looks the same as that horn, including the matching dimple at the mouthpiece and crease on the lower front curve.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Actually the cart is of correct size (or just a little on the large side) for a Lego Friends or Disney Princess mini-fig. Chest high on a "standard" mini-fig. Too small for Playmobil. I have 2 of them and on closer inspection I could find a logo on the second (it was too worn on the first). Logo says "PLUS" which is a Dutch supermarket chain, so I'm now guessing some sort of promo-material. I never shop at PLUS as I have several other supermarkets closer by, so I have no idea what they have done for promotions.

Comment: @CitizenRon I think you should make that an answer, or edit it into the main answer to expand its completeness.

Comment: I would, but a few unverified sales labels on EBay would seem to be to be a bit less than definitive evidence.  Without finding something official from the manufacturer, I thought I'd just post what I found as corroboration of the theory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The race car nose part is officially called [Wedge 4 x 2 x 1 1/3 with 1 x 4 Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93589&name=Wedge%204%20x%202%20x%201%201/3%20with%201%20x%204%20Base&category=%5BWedge%5D#T=S&C=5&O=%7B%22color%22:5,%22iconly%22:0%7D):
[image: Wedge 4 x 2 x 1 1/3 with 1 x 4 Base]

It's found in a [single set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=30190-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), alongside with the [Slope, Curved 4 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61678&idColor=5#T=C&C=5) and the [Sticker Sheet for Set 30190](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30190stk01&idColor=0#T=C&C=0) which contains all stickers applied to that part.

The canopy with a "broken-glass" texture is a [Wedge 4 x 4 Fractured Polygon Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64867#T=S&C=98&O=%7B%22color%22:%2298%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D): [image: Wedge 4 x 4 Fractured Polygon Top]

The bugle and the shopping cart are most probably not LEGO pieces. If they were, they would be found under the category [Minifigure, Utensil](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&catString=18&catType=P), but the only bugle there is [this one](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=71342#T=C), which looks completely different, just like the only shopping cart is an [entirely other design](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=49649#T=C&C=36).

Comment: That is helpful. Going through the related sets I can definitely identify 30190 (Ferrari polybag) for the nose and the slope with the stickers (I've got another 1x2 tile with sticker as well from that set). Stickers are obviously on the wrong piece. The canopy seems to be from a Nexo Knights set, but there are 2 candidates (based on the mini-figs I also have) and either one wouldn't be complete.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought to look for the car nose under the "wedge" heading. I was looking car, slope and wing categories.